# How to fix this error when creating a project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I create a project, I get this error, if anyone came across tell me how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: It literally tells you at least two ways to fix that error in the provided screenshot. Aside from that, your question is extremely barebones and is likely to be closed as overly broad. Please take the Stack Overflow [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which will have been recommended to you before you asked this question to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

1. Look into your `package.json`, if you have jest there either remove it if you dont use it, or set the version to `"24.7.1"` care that you dont use `^` in front of the version.
2. If another package is using jest at 24.8.0 then the same applies set in you `package.json` the version to `"24.7.1"`